# How to render one side of a cube with different material than the other sides

Tags: rendering

Picking up 3D graphics since 2004, so I'm a bit lost now.

I'm trying to make a cube of metal look rough cut on 5 sides, and mirror smooth on one side.

I've managed to control the roughness with vectors for the bumb and so on, but I hit the wall trying to assign another property of the one side to be smooth.

I'm thinking it should just be to separate the face that are to be smooth from the rest.

When looking into this site's answers, it looks like I just have to select the face I want to separate with key "Y". It's separates all right, but I can't seem to assign a specific material to that separated side, it always includes the other sides vectored bump.

Why is a separated mesh face still "slaved" to the other faces when it comes to material assignment?

Comment: You do not, and should not, separate a face if all you want is to assign a different material to it.  You just add another material in the materials tab, make sure it is highlighted, tab into edit mode, select the face(s) you want and click the 'assign' button.

Comment: YES! Mode confusion from my sida again. The thing I've been doing was to create and select from the material drop-down menu directly below the "Assign"-button. That seem to change between materials only, instead of creating a new material in the larger list directly above the "assign"-button! Thank you so much for Your help, photox!

Comment: Follow-question here is: what's that drop down material menu for then? Now that I've created another material in the larger list I mentioned above, the drop down many seem to reflect all materials in the list, like two ways of choosing materials next to each other..

Comment: Blender is weird with it's materials.  If you click the + button you create a new 'material slot' this is saying, ok I plan on adding a material here in the future.  You then have the option of choosing an existing material for that slot (from the dropdown menu) or clicking 'new' and creating a new material from scratch.  

In the common case that there are no material slots, for instance when you create a new object, and you click the 'new' button, it creates --simultaneously --  a new material slot, AND a new material, which is a diffuse white.

Comment: I see, yeah, seem to be lots of open doors for future development. Thank you very much for you input. Work in progress now :)

Answer (score 0):

"You do not, and should not, separate a face if all you want is to assign a different material to it. You just add another material in the materials tab, make sure it is highlighted, tab into edit mode, select the face(s) you want and click the 'assign' button. – photox 2 hours ago"